# how to optimize this method for "from query to output shortcut"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i wrote this method, but i wanted to optimize it.
i think `TResult output` ( parameter in `Into` method in `Pagination.cs` ) and also `new HomeProjectViewModel()` ( in `ProjectService.cs` ) can be removed, but i can't do!

is it possible to remove this parameter from method?

**Pagination.cs**

```
 public static class Pagination
{

    public static async Task<TResult> Into<T, TSource, TResult>(this IQueryable<T> query, Func<List<T>, List<TSource>> source, TResult output, int page, int showLimit)
    {
        if (query == null) return output;

        var que = page > 1
            ? await query.Skip(showLimit * (page - 1)).Take(showLimit).Cacheable().ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)
            : await query.Take(showLimit).Cacheable().ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        var list = source.Invoke(que);

        var type = output.GetType();
        var pages = type.GetProperty("Pages");
        var currentPage = type.GetProperty("CurrentPage");
        var items = type.GetProperty("Items");

        if (pages == null || currentPage == null || items == null) return output;

        pages.SetValue(output, Numbers.RoundToUp((double)(await query.CountAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)) / showLimit));
        currentPage.SetValue(output, page);
        items.SetValue(output, list);

        return output;
    }
```

**ProjectService.cs**

```
public async Task<HomeProjectViewModel> HomeProjects(int page, int showLimit = 5)
    {
        var query = from project in _project
                    let pictures = from picture in project.Pictures where !picture.Deleted select picture.Filename
                    where !project.Deleted && !project.Hidden
                    orderby project.Added descending
                    select new
                    {
                        project.SmartId,
                        project.Text,
                        pictures,
                    };

        return await query.Into(que =>
            que.Select(project => new HomeProjectItemViewModel
            {
                SmartId = project.SmartId,
                Name = project.Text,
                Image = project.pictures.SelectRandom()
            }).ToList(), new HomeProjectViewModel(), page, showLimit);
    }
```

**HomeProjectViewModel.cs**

```
   public class HomeProjectViewModel
    {
        public List<HomeProjectItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
        public int Pages { get; set; }
    }
```

this method will be a shortcut way to create a class that contains pages, current page and etc...

in my project, many methods are look like `HomeProjects()`

and i wanted to create method instead of many lines of codes.